# Mysql create procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

how i can create a procedure to delete comment as row but i have foreign key in other table "reply" 
to understand my problem please show my image:

create procedure:

[image]

table comments:

[image]

table reply:

[image]

probleme :

[image]

i want make a code to create a procedure to delete a row in table comment where comments="..."
like this :

```
create procedure delcomments as
delete from comments where comments.comments=@comment1

@comment1 : input comment by me
```

Answer (score 2):

Define the foreign key with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

```
ALTER TABLE reply
            ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_comment)
                            REFERENCES comments
                                       (id)
                            ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

That way, when you delete a comment, with a simple `DELETE FROM comments ...`, the referencing replies get deleted too, without the need of any procedure.

Comment: where i put this code i receive error:
'The following query has failed: "CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `del_comment`(IN `id1` INT(255)) NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER ALTER TABLE reply ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_comment) REFERENCES comments (id) ON DELETE CASCADE; delete from comments where comments.id=id1"
MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delete from comments where comments.id=id1' at line 6'

Comment: @محمدعباس In the query editor of whatever SQL client you use.

Comment: Server: MySQL (127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP)
Server type: MySQL
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 5.7.23 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10

Comment: @محمدعباس This is no code for a procedure. You just execute that once to alter the table's definition (actually the foreign key constraint's).

Comment: plz show picture "probleme"
in this code updatet ,i want delete comment using id i put ur code but i receive error above